# Data access issue when app is removed to SDcard Android

Tags: android, eclipse, path, cocos2d-x, android-context

I've a game which stores data on device by getting path using this function

```
context.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath()+"/";
```

After playing some levels, if I move game to SD Card (by default it is installed on device storage) then it fails reading from that path. Can anyone point out what is going wrong, or link to another question with similar problem? I don't have deep understanding in android so I know I am making some silly mistake.

Comment: What do you mean with 'remove to SD Card'?

Comment: And what is the absolute parh in both situations?

Comment: @greenapps by default app is installed on device storage, after installing if it is moved to SD card

Comment: You did not tell the paths yet. And your subject is unchanged.

Comment: You also did not tell how the sd card is used. As portable storage? As internal memory? Which Android version?